# Perform action after coming from a closed state - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently have this:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
    ...
}
```

and that works when I don't quit the app, it simply is in the background, but when I quit it, the code inside there that is suppoused to check for a time, doesn't work.

I also tried putting it in 
`.onAppear() {`

but that doesn't workout either :/

How can I once the app has been closed, then opened, as soon as it opens run an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adding the following code to perform an action when your app starts:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
    // do your action here
    ....
}
```